# http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000 both are invalid website URL in Twitter Developer App for User Authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-twitter

I am exploring Passport.js and authentication with Twitter OAuth, In which I have created demo application in Twitter developer app and have to add callback URL and website URL.

So I am facing error while adding website URL. As it showing in the image that website URL is required and also invalid URL.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr6sW.png]

Comment: Is that URL actually used in the authentication process? Try `https://example.com`.

Comment: Yes, it's redirected url. So can't use https://example.com

Comment: Have you tried to use `http://localhost` only? Does that work?

Comment: If localhost does not work, use a service/tool like ngrok

Comment: Hey @node_modules, The problem is that its showing invalid URL as I use localhost weather its http://localhost or http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000

Answer (score 0):

use vercel to deploy project and use vercel deplyment link it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).